# GeoServer - change native SRS of cascaded WMS (other from Capabilities)

Tags: geoserver, wms, getcapabilities

**Short story:**
How to change native srs of cascaded WMS service in GeoServer admin GUI? How to change native SRS from epsg 32633 to 4326? This native srs is blocked to change (it is somehow set automatically).

**Long story**:
I cascade WMS service with my GeoServer. Problem is that layer inside GeoServer sets "Native reference system" for some reason as `EPSG:32633` (it is almost last in Capabilities, why it doesn't take `epsg:4326`, which is first???).

From this `epsg:32633` I need to transform WMS to `epsg:4326`, but reprojection from native to declared gives me wrong BBOX coordinates, which ends in shift of my layer compared to the base map.

32633 BBOX coordinates are reprojected to 4326 are different, than those in Capabilities... Changing to other native srs can maybe force GeoServer to take good coordinates as they are in Capabilities.

```
<westBoundLongitude> 11.349143 </westBoundLongitude>
<eastBoundLongitude> 19.062675 </eastBoundLongitude>
<southBoundLatitude> 48.198780 </southBoundLatitude>
<northBoundLatitude> 51.668105 </northBoundLatitude>
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84" minx="11.349143" miny="48.198780" maxx="19.062675" maxy="51.668105"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326" minx="48.198780" miny="11.349143" maxx="51.668105" maxy="19.062675"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:32633" minx="244254.160680" miny="5342402.535258" maxx="798540.723911" maxy="5730646.738059"/>
```

When I tried to load WMS to QGIS I got the same "layer shift" error except when I set WMS projection to 5514 (this one made layer show correctly), which is not supported by GeoServer.

Here is list of supported epsg's written in GetCapabilities:

```
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS> <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS> <CRS>EPSG:102067</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:5514</CRS> <CRS>EPSG:28403</CRS> <CRS>EPSG:4258</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3035</CRS> <CRS>EPSG:32633</CRS> <CRS>EPSG:102100</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:102113</CRS>
```

Capabilities are [here](http://geoportal.gov.cz/arcgis/services/CENIA/cenia_rt_II_vojenske_mapovani/MapServer/WMSServer?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities)!

Comment: Which GeoServer version?

Comment: I deal with this problem in version 2.7.0, which is version used by my institution, where I need to use this layer. When I was developing at home with version 2.5.2 few months back, I didnt get this error when I was using same native epsg. First thing that come in my mind is that if the source layer and capabilities are ok, but I think it should be, because it is raster layer provided by major government institution.

Comment: As I discused with data provider the WMS capabilities are wrong because of bug in server software which cannot deal with reprojection correctly. Question how to change native CRS of external WMS inside geoserver is still unclear for me - this should fix my error.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding your meaning here, but  I don't think you can change the native projection system of a remote data source, what you might be able to do is change the default projection system for that service when it is used within your WMS.  The order the CRS are listed in does not imply which CRS is the native projection (that is the projection the data is actually held in) just the projections that are supported by the service.